# In Swift, I have a func that copies a folder recursively, and uses async calls. I would like to add a completion handler. Any elegant solution?

Tags: swift, recursion

In my macOS App, I am using a smb library that has APIs for uploading and downloading files, but lacks a built-in mechanism for doing the same with entire folders, so I am trying to add this feature. I wrote a recursive pair of functions for upload / download, and they work well, but now I would like to add a completion handler to the methods that would fire at the end of the copy operation of the entire folder. I have added the closure as an argument, and when calling the method recursively, I pass nil as the completion handler, so I can be aware that the completion handler fires only for the enclosing folder. The problem is, the smb library I am using uses async calls, so my first implementation, that checks if the handler is nil and if not so fires it, runs too early because the main loop finishes of course before the recursive calls operations end. I think I can find a solution to this problem, but I am looking for a Swift elegant solution. I have a strong feeling that somebody with more experience can solve this implementation problem more easily and in a less cumbersome way that I would. My code is simply:

```
func downloadFolder(into url: URL, fromPath: String, completionHandler: ( (Error?) -> Void)?) {}
```

I have a simple loop, and if the item is a folder it calls the same function recursively, otherwise it downloads the item using the built-in API. The hierarchy of the folders is carefully recreated both in upload and in download.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Consider the Combine framework? I use it for everything asynchronous nowadays.

Comment: Thanks ! it seems fabulous, and I will certainly try to learn it. Unfortunately, my app is for macOS and I would like to keep at least Sierra and Later... My understanding is that it is targeted for Catalina and later... Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your approach without seeing your implementation, but hopefully what I wrote might be of some use. Perhaps you could use the `DispatchGroup` class and call its `.enter()` for every async task you start and `.leave()` whenever that task is done. Once the number of `.leave()` calls match `.enter()` the `.notify()` will execute an async block which you can call you original completion block from.

### Wrapper Function

This is your original function you would call.

```
func downloadFolder(into url: URL, fromPath: String, completionHandler: ( (Error?) -> Void)?) {
    
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    var error:Error?
    
    _downloadFolder(group: group, into: url, fromPath: fromPath)
    
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completionHandler?(error)
    }
}
```

### Recursive function

This is the private recursive one

```
private func _downloadFolder(group: DispatchGroup, into url: URL, fromPath: String) {
    print("Entering:", fromPath)
    group.enter()
    
    let filesToCopy = Int.random(in: 1...3)
    
    //Base case: No more subfiles
    //Simulating in a weird fashion
    if filesToCopy == 0 || fromPath.count > 10 {
        print("Done here:", fromPath)
        
        //Call this when your async task is finished, like you would a completion handler.
        group.leave()
    }else{
    //Recursive case: There's still files to copy on this path.
        for i in 0..<filesToCopy {
            let subPath = "\(fromPath)/\(i + 1)"
            _downloadFolder(group: group, into: url, fromPath: subPath)
        }
        group.leave()
    }
}
```

### Implementation

```
downloadFolder(
    into: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!,
    fromPath: "Root"
) { (err) in
    if let err = err {
        print(err)
    }else{
        print("Finished copying with no errors.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, excellent answer ! you solved my problem without even looking at my implementation Great ! I will edit my question and insert some more background to make the post more useful to other users. Thanks again !